# What's wrong with this calculation function?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote everything correctly, but it's not working. I can't understand; I don't see a problem, but it still doesn't work. My English isn't very good, so I have trouble explaining in detail.

I just don't know why this doesn't work.

```js
function calc() {
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
    var op = (document.querySelector("#operator").value);
    var calculate;

    if (op == "add") {
        calculate = a + b;
    } else if (op =="min") {
        calculate = a - b;
    } else if (op =="div") {
        calculate = a / b;
    } else if (op =="mul") {
        calculate = a * b;
    }

    console.log(calculate);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    
    Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1">
    <br>
    Value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
    Operator: 
    
    <select id="operator">
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="min">Minus</option>
        <option value="div">Divide</option>
        <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
    </select>

    <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>

</form>

</body>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Replace `var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);` with `var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);`

Comment: You should try to read the `error` and `console log`. It would help you tremendously.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. If you had and run it, the console error is very clear

Comment: What have you tried to check **where** this script goes wrong? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to declare the var 'b' in line number 3. The correct code should be :

```
var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);

var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
```